# Django - Change default widgets of fields in MultiColumnField

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-models

in my application I need to use a lot of legacy databases that change frequently, that means the views and templates I use must be able to handle a lot of different cases. In each of these legacy tables are a few fields that are standardized. I used [this](https://gist.github.com/gipi/2401143) multi-column field implementation to wrap them into one field, as I want to assign a bit of special behaviour to them later on. That worked nicely, the forms automatically showed all the fields contained in the `MultiColumnField` with their default widgets. Saving to the db also works.

But now I want to change the default widget for these fields to something different, and I really don't know where to assign them.

I tried using MultiWidgets, but that didn't seem to do what I want. I then tried to set the `form_class` in the generic view that manages the form:

```
class ThemeCreateView(CreateView):
    def __init__(self, model=None, template_name = None, success_url = None):
        self.model = model
        self.template_name = template_name
        self.success_url = success_url

        self.form_class =  modelform_factory(self.model, widgets=
                                             {'st_name': CustomWidget(),
                                              'st_key': CustomWidget(),
                                              'st_meta': CustomWidget(),
        super(ThemeCreateView, self).__init__()
```

I had to assign everything in `__init__` because I don't know which model will call the view. The view is called with `.as_view()` in the urls.py.

The problems is, the widgets I assign here are ignored, the form still shows the default widgets. I presume they get reset to default at a later point? Do I have to override somewhere else?

I read that I could use the templates to change it to another widget (at least if I want to use the HiddenInput-Widget), but the templates also don't know which models will hit them, so I think can't really use anything else than `{{forms.as_p}}`

Any idea where in the view / where else I could set the widgets? Maybe directly in the `MultiColumnField`? Hard-coding the fields in wouldn't be a problem, as I use the field only for this special case, but I don't know where to start there.

If anything remains unclear, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `widgets` kwarg customize existing form, that should be passed via `form` kwarg
`Form = modelform_factory(Book, form=BookForm, widgets={"title": Textarea()})`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function

Or you can define forms manually and refuse from using modelform_factory

```
class BaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.base_fields['st_name'].widget = CustomWidget()
        self.base_fields['st_key'].widget = CustomWidget()
        self.base_fields['st_meta'].widget = CustomWidget()

class NumberOneForm(BaseForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NumberOneModel

class NumberTwoForm(BaseForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NumberTwoModel
```

Comment: Ok, that's probably it, but I'm not sure if I understood you right. That's what I did with my modelform_factory, the form should be right now, but if I do it like this it doesn't work : `Form =  modelform_factory(self.model, CreateView.get_form_class(self), widgets= {'st_name':Textarea(), ... })` Anything else I need to change?

Comment: I was missing a prefix in the fieldnames, it works now, thanks!